# How do I write the division symbol on a web page where one term is written and the next term below it with the overline below the first term?

Tags: html

[image]

I wanted this type of output on a page, what code should I write the code?

Comment: That is one blurred image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps..
https://jsfiddle.net/q3e8fLny/

```
<div>
    <p class='top'>xp</p>
    <p class='bottom'> p</p>
</div>


.top{
   border-bottom:1px solid black;
   display:inline-block;
 }
.bottom{
   transform:translateY(-30px);
 }
```